# segmentation fault, lists in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I tried to sort directly the numbers I enter in a linked list using two functions the first one add the element at the head the second one which contain the segmentation fault is supposed to exploit the first one to do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct cellule
{
    int val;
    struct cellule *suivant;
} cellule;
typedef struct cellule* liste;

liste insert_tete(liste L,int n)
{

    liste p;

    p=malloc(sizeof(cellule));
    p->val=n;
    p->suivant=L;
    return p;
}//ok :)
liste insert_croissant(liste L,int n)
{
    if(!L)
    {
        L=insert_tete(L,n);
        return L;
    }

    liste p,q;
    for(q=L,p=L; (p!=NULL )&&(n> (p->val)) ; q=p,p=p->suivant); //

    p=insert_tete(p,n);
    q->suivant=p;
    return L;
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: `insert_croissant()` sounds delicious!

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc in C.  There is no reason to do so and it can actually hide the fact that you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` (without the cast, the nonexistant function is implied to return `int`, which will fail, but the cast hides it).  C has no problem coercing a `void*` to any other pointer type implicitly.

Comment: Also, descriptive variable names are nice.

Comment: Is the empty list properly initialized? That means, is `suivant` set to `NULL`? Also, both the code and question are **hardly** legible.

Comment: The `for` loop variable update expression is not well-defined: `q=p, p=p->suivant`, does not guarantee `q` is set before `p` is updated.

Comment: Don't hide pointers types behind typedefs, either.  `liste` doesn't indicate pointerness at all, so seeing the `->` operator being used on values of that type is a little jarring. Hiding that information will eventually lead to heartburn.

Comment: Yes, only use `tyepdef`s for pointers when they are truly opaque (which yours are not.  I have to know it is a pointer to handle things correctly). And even though using non-English in your code is probably  a bad idea, I was referring to `p, q, L, n` etc.

Comment: debugger tell me that the error is in the for line

Comment: @BrettHale, yes it is well defined. The comma here is a "comma operator" and each such comma operator defines a sequence point.

Comment: @user1327656, bienvenue to stackoverflow. As you can see here, to address a particular one of the commenters, put an "@" in front of the name.

Comment: I stared at this for ten minutes and could not spot the error. I suppose the error *must be* the caller passing an uninitialised pointer to the first argument of insert_croissant().  BTW: as others have said, the code is hardly readable.

Comment: oops - confusing comma separated expressions with lvalues.

Comment: @RafałRawicki you were absolutely right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a problem where the list can get corrupted in certain cases; it's easy to get the list into a state where it's not properly terminated (and possibly 'lose' nodes from the list).  And that situation could cause problems depending on how other code might manipulate the list.

If you try to add a new node on a list that isn't empty, but the new value is less than or equal to the first node's value, the list will end up being a circular list with two nodes on it. Any nodes after the one that was at the head of the list are lost.

This happens because in that case both `p` and `q` will point to that node when `insert_tete(p,n)` is called. After `insert_tete(p,n)` returns, `p-suivant` and `q` will be pointing to the node at the head of the list.  so when

```
q->suivant = p;
```

is executed, the list will be circular and 'extra' nodes will be lost.

Depending on how your other operations act on the list, (especially if/how you delete elements) you could find yourself with a dangling pointer left in a `suivant` field (which may cause a segfault), or end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

By no means do I believe this will fix it, but there is at least one bug in your code.

Consider the case where L is initialized, but n < L->val:

```
// p = L, q = L;
// Let L = [val|->...
p=insert_tete(p,n);
// p = [n|->[val|->...
q->suivant=p;
// q = L
// Therefore [val|->[n|->L
// And you've just made your linked list circular.
```

Comment: You're right. The insert_tete() will set p->suivant = p. Furthermore, the pointer that points to p will not be updated, so the q subchain will become disconnected from the p chain.

Comment: Sorry about the extra answer though - I haven't been active enough to actually have privilege to comment...

Comment: No, it is excellent. I could not spot it after studying it for ten minutes. The problem is: there are too many aliases floating around. (I can't vote, because I am not registered) **please vote parent up!**

Comment: @wildplasser What do you mean "not registered"? You're a regular here, aren't you? Anyway, Michael, yes, wildplasser is right, it's a good answer that adds something new, so it gets you at least 10 points nearer to comment privileges (in other words, +1 from me). I overlooked that too, btw.

Comment: Well: click on my bio. It says unregistered. It's my love for Graucho Marx that keeps me from registering.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't see a bio at users/905902, but I see 'member for 7 months'. Accidentally registered without noticing?

Comment: After the nickname it says "Unregistered less info". (at least here it does)

Answer (score 1):

```
liste insert_croissant(liste L,int n)
{
    if(!L)
    {
        L=insert_tete(L,n);
        return L;
    }
```

Here we know that `L` is not `NULL`

```
    liste p,q;
    for(q=L,p=L; (p!=NULL )&&(n> (p->val)) ; q=p,p=p->suivant); //
```

The only way to get a legitimate segfault here is that one of the pointers `p` follows is a non-0 pointer that doesn't point to a properly allocated `struct cellule`, but to some inaccessible memory. Then trying to access `p->val` (or `p->suivant`) causes a segfault.

The most common way (in my limited experience) to get into that situation is forgetting to initialise the first pointer to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version using pointer-to-pointer. Note: there is no special case for the empty list.

```
struct cellule {
    int val;
    struct cellule *suivant;
    };

struct cellule *insert_croissant(struct cellule **LL, int val)
{

    struct cellule *p,**pp;

    for(pp=LL  ; *pp && (*pp)->val < val ; pp = &(*pp)->suivant) {;}
      /* When we arrive here, pp points to whatever pointer happens
      ** to point to our current node.
      ** - If the list was empty, *pp==NULL
      ** - if the place to insert happens to be the tail of the list, *p is also NULL        
      ** - in all cases, *pp should be placed after the new node, and the new node's pointer should be assigned to *pp
      */
    p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->val = val;
    p->suivant = *pp;
    *pp = p;

    return *LL;

}
```

Comment: this is far better , i think in that case it is not a good idea to use the existing function which insert at the head, thank you!